# Bootstrap4 issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

My Site is breaking in IE 11 which is officially supported by Bootstrap 4.
Any idea what I need to have to support the browser?

I have tried putting this in the head tag but no resolution thus far:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Check out this site in IE 11 & Chrome: onaseer87.github.io/medcouture

Comment: Can you add a link to the site (besides github)? Perhaps explain what exactly do you mean by 'breaking'? What happens when you open it in IE? How should it work?

Comment: That's the site on github pages. The solution is that I cannot use ES6 JS if I want to support IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough research of all file types I found the issue was in JS. I was using ES6 which is not supported in IE.

For example: Using of Let instead of var, or template literals couldn't trans-pile in IE.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check your site with IE and chrome.

First issue I found that one part of the web page was not displaying in IE browser.

I check in the developer tools and found the line below.

```
<div class="container my-5" id="touch">
```

You can notice that **#touch** css class is applied on it. It has **opacity** set as **0**.

If you unchecked it than it will show the page part properly.

[image]

If this css code is written by you than you modify it. If this code added by Bootstrap than you may need to apply your own css to fix the issue because we cannot modify the code from Bootstrap.

other thing I notice that your JQuery slider show only 2 Divs in it. For that it is better you can test it separately. It can be hard for us to directly check it in site. It can help to narrow down the issue.